# What is the difference between Dynamic and Strongly Typed Views in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got a url http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views

they create a not strongly typed view but at they refer `@model dynamic` at top of the view.

but rest of the code looks like normal strongly typed view. anyone can tell me what is the difference between Dynamic and Strongly Typed Views in MVC.

When one should use dynamic view. discuss with example when dynamic view is required ?

Comment: You should never use a dynamic view. Unless you don't understand what Model-View-Controller means. Or, if you don't need a model at all.

Comment: Cuz you're lazy and don't want to write DTO wrappers, or for whatever reason cannot. https://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2010/06/23/dynamic-view-page-mvc-without-a-view-model/

Comment: the link i have pasted here from MS web site. when they publish or write out dynamic view that means it has some usage. so i am just curious to know where to use it......looking for hints and guide if anyone ever has used it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that a dynamic view won't enforce compile-time type-checking (binding to properties etc). You can name and bind any property you want. At run time, if it can't find it in the model, that's when you'll get an error. [It's the same as the dynamic keyword in the language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

As to why or when to use it, generally speaking, don't. It's a workaround. Write a wrapper class, write the DTO, write an adapter, there's plenty of ways to make a strongly typed object to bind to. Implement an interface or something.

Rarely you might come across a situation where it's just not feasible (legacy code, 3rd party libraries?) to do it the "right" way. That's when you might be stuck with it. Run time errors are not fun to try to recover from - try to never use dynamic views.

The only time I personally have used it was to mock up test layouts and I didn't want to actually create full models yet. I'd not use it for production code.